Sonicwall mobile vpn client issue on android and ios devices: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
I'm trying to make a GET request of a png from firebase storage.
I've an angular app running on an nginx within a docker container.
I'm using a vpn to host this web server, the vpn clients i'm using are SonicWall Netextender (Windows) and Sonicwall mobile connect for (Android, IOS and MacOS). The only difference with this mobile vpn client is that it uses a TLSv1.2/SSLVPN protocol while in the rest only SSLVPN.
The issue is that the GET request for getting a particular image is not being resolved just in the case of connecting with Android and IOS:
Failed GET request
I tried incognito window, multiple browsers, clear dns cache of the browser, ...with no result.
Dns lookup on android mobile device
Vpn monitor (Mac)
Vpn monitor (Android)

From the Android or IOS device, using a browser or a network tool are you able to resolve the domain name "firebasestorage.googleapis.com" ?

Hi Greg, i'm not able to resolve it, it throws the same error as in the console:  net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

So the issue is that your devices are unable to resolve the domain name.  That is what needs to be fixed.  It is a networking problem, not a Firebase problem.  Can your devices get to any domain name?

I can't get to any domain... may be is something with my vpn/client

Your device's network configuration is not allowing it to resolve domain names.  There are a few things that could lead to that.  Ultimately you want your device to be able to resolve domain names.  I cannot predict where the issue would be coming from.
